# To Rescue Nonbooting OS X with Grub?

Tags: macos, startup, grub

I had Refind bootloader in Macbook Air 2013-mid. My disk has OSX and broken Ubuntu. Ubuntu messed up my bootloader such that it starts only. 
I cannot go to grub/refind by pressing ALT, ALT-R, ...
My SIP is disabled.

I followed the guides [here](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/39426/25388).
I am now in `grub>` command prompt where I managed to get by pressing `ESC` at startup. In `grub`, `ls` gives

```
(proc) (hd0) (hd1) (hd3) (hd1,gpt4) (hd1,gpt2) (hd1,gpt1) error: failure reading sector 0x0 from `hd2'
```

where

- `hd1` is my SSD find out by `ls (hd1)`
- `(hd1,gpt1)` EFI here, fat filesystem, probably swap size 20kB
- `(hd1,gpt2)` 75 GB here, probably OS X
- `(hd1,gpt3)` Recovery HD, not sure what
- `(hd1,gpt4)` Ubuntu 16.04, 45 Gb here

So I need to setup a bootloader which has `(hd1,gpt2)` and `(hd1,gpt4)` in the same table. I may still have `refind` but not sure, because Ubuntu probably replaced it. 
**Problem**: `ls (hd1,gpt2)/` gives

```
error: unknown filesystem
```

I cannot configure the bootloader apparently back with Linux grub. 
If I could see the contents, I would like to do

```
set root='(hd1,gpt2)'
...
```

I really would like to start some **live system** to fix the thing, but I cannot find any key to boot from USB.

### Updates in Linux side

I did many update and upgrade cycles on the Linux side. So the Linux kernel is now 4.4. In startup, I get only Grub menu where is no OS X. Just the Ubuntu and its variations. 
So I think the **problem is just to link the OS X to Grub** but I am not sure about if when I could read OS X filesystem in `grub>`.

### Unsuccessful attempt of installing refind in Linux

In Linux, install `refind` again

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:rodsmith/refind
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install refind
```

and answer `yes`. Restart. However, Grub is still there but not refind.

---

How can you fix the bootloader in Macbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run the `refind-install` script with `sudo` in the OS X side. I could not get to the recovery mode. This solved the problem.

Comment: Your question referred to a boot loader. Grub, for example, is a boot loader. Refind is not. Refind is boot manager.

Comment: I added it to a tag. Anything that solves the thing is ok for me here.

Comment: This doesn’t help me because it implies I can somehow get into macOS in the first place. All I can get into is Grub and Ubuntu currently. ;(